# optgroup label is not bold in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Group 1">
    <option>Option 1.1</option>
  </optgroup> 
  <optgroup label="Group 2">
    <option>Option 2.1</option>
    <option>Option 2.2</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Group 3" disabled>
    <option>Option 3.1</option>
    <option>Option 3.2</option>
    <option>Option 3.3</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

In Firefox and IE by default, it is bold. I am having an issue with Chrome (Version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)).

What I have tried so far

In CSS file

optgroup { font-weight: bold !important; }

https://jsbin.com/xekamenixo/edit?html,css,output

Comment: is bold for me using same version & build. Not as pronounced as in Firefox though

Comment: Are you on Mac or windows ? I am in Mac, does that make a difference?

Comment: Not sure...am using windows though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested it again. 
I verified that there is an issue with OSX.
But It works fine with windows (chrome).